# How to prevent myself from rebooting windows when VMWare Workstation is running?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, vmware-workstation, reboot

I use the free VMWare Workstation version to run VM's on Windows 10, and I keep the Workstation window out of the way on a second Windows desktop since the free version does not support minimizing to the system tray.

I'd like to set a reminder for myself when I restart or shutdown Windows, so I can close running VM's first, otherwise Workstation does a hard poweroff for each one.

Is there an app or a Windows feature that can prevent restarts or shutdowns ? Support for automatic rules like "prevent shutdown if `workstation.exe` is running" would be even better.

Comment: The way you describe, not that I have seen.  Workstation Pro has a system tray icon saying that Workstation is running. That can be exposed so as to always visible.  See if Player has the same feature

Comment: Perhaps a Scheduled Task on Shutdown can be created to close VMWare gracefully. See https://superuser.com/questions/165142/using-task-scheduler-to-run-a-task-before-shutdown and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/schedule-a-shutdown-task-in-windows-10/2fe26101-d153-4b5e-8d59-6f3f4e6b1b83